# Change section header title when using UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am using `UISearchDisplayController` to search through a table view. The table view has two sections - Open and Closed. In `numberOfSectionsInTableView` I use if **(**`tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView`**)** to set the amount of sections to 1 when I am using the search bar. But the title is still Open.

Is there a way to temporarily change the section title while searching?

Comment: can't you use the same condition "if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)"  also in the function to display the tile

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text.length == 0) {
        return @"";
    } else {
        return @"Open";
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, unfortunately it did not work. It is still "Open". I also tried if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {
        return @"";
    } else {
        return [_sectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
    }

Comment: @pouncelciot I forget you are using only tableView for multiple datasource.. try to check the text of the `searchBar`

Comment: Do you know a way to do this? I searched but could not find it.

Comment: @pouncelciot Can you post your implements of the `titleForHeaderInSection`  ?